# Band Playing without some of its Current Members

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests

I was wondering: is there in English a specific phrase to denote a music band not playing with its whole current group of members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on context...

For a small music group such as a rock band, for example, I'd mention the missing current members:

> ***"The legendary Prog-Rock group YES will be touring the US this summer minus its iconic lead vocalist, Jon Anderson."***

If it's a large group such as the US Army Band, for example, I might call the smaller group an ***"ensemble"*** made up of members from the US Army Band.

Comment: Thanks Kristina. What if I'm talking about more than one concert and the missing member is not the same in all instances?

Comment: Similar to what Kristina says, I have seen people say current lineup, eg, "Supertramp will be playing live with their current lineup featuring the original member X"